# Best way to integrate/embed a node js project in a non-node application

Tags: node.js

I have a node (+express and socket.io) project which runs a server presenting data in html. But i dont want users to go to the specific url or i.p. address. Instead i would like to integrate the node application in an existing webpage. (For example a Wordpress site)

So what would be the best way to integrate a node project into an existing project that is not bulit with Node? Embedding it in an iFrame doesn´t seem optimal ;) 
I guess jQuery.load() wont work since it´s not listening for server side changes and the whole point with node goes missing :)

Kind regards
Henrik

Comment: I don't quite understand the whole point or picture of what you're trying to achieve but you can use jquery $.ajax(..) call to load the content and dynamically render it within the target webpage if that's what you're after

Comment: Ok. Does everyone using node run it as a standalone server? There must be lots of people that want to integrate their node projects as a part of, for example, an existing PHP project.

Comment: That's two completely different technologies. You can't just take node application and "put" it to PHP project. If you want to merge two project using different technologies you have to either re-implement one to another or run two servers each handling client request for its functionality.

Comment: Okay, i see your point! I know i will have to have two servers and that i have to communicate between the two servers via for example json if they are to communicate. What i want to do is implementing a standalone node application in my PHP project if possible but i guess there are no great way of going about this except for an iFrame.

Comment: Say for example i would like to implement a simple live updated "Current users browsing your site: 12" (which is really easy to build in node) on my PHP webiste, is there no good way of going about this?

Comment: From your PHP page that is rendered in the browser, use Ajax and/or socket.io to communicate with the node.js server and then insert/modify content in your page with client-side Javascript as you retrieve data or are sent notifications.  You will have to enable CORS on the node.js server so the browser won't block the cross origin communications.

Comment: So you mean i can make something like xhttp.open("GET", "Path_to_my_server", true);? I´ll try that!